# How do I organize two sets of data, one of them an updated list, including multiple columns in each set?

Tags: excel

I have a pretty large excel sheet. 12 columns and 800 rows in column 1-5 and about about 600 in 6-12.

It is all product numbers, and prices, and other information. The first 2 columns are the updated prices for the same product numbers. Some products are new and thus 200 more rows....

My question is, how do I line up the product numbers WITH the prices next to eachother? For example. It looks like:
Product name 1      price 1      product name 2     Price 2
A.                             100.              B.                       150
B.                             150.              A.                        100
C.                             200.             D.                         250
D.                             250

I want to line up A, B and D. Additionally, C is only in list 1, I want to put it on the bottom of the newly aligned list with the 200 other new products and prices. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you paste the current table and the desired outcome in table format?